# Doctrine difference between prePersist and construct method

Tags: symfony, doctrine

According to the [doctrine documentary](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/events.html):

> The prePersist event occurs for a given entity before the respective
>   EntityManager persist operation for that entity is executed. **It should
>   be noted that this event is only triggered on initial persist of an
>   entity** (i.e. it does not trigger on future updates).

The last part is important and makes me wonder; is there a difference in that case with the `__contruct()` method?

Let's say I want to set the creation date and time (`createdAt`) for an enitity. I can do this with the lifecycle callback:

```
/**
 * @ORM\PrePersist
 */
public function setTimestamp()
{
    $this->setCreatedAt(new \DateTime('now'));
}
```

Or I can use the contructor like this:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->createdAt = new \DateTime('now');
}
```

Does this do exactly the same? And if so, why is there the `PrePersist` lifecycle callback?

Comment: There is no practical difference in your example.  There are times when you might want to do a bit of processing using information not available in the constructor.  In which case PrePersist might come in handy.  And while this is strictly my opinion, avoid Doctrine events if you can.  PrePersist is fairly straight forward but some of the others have strict limitations and can cause a great deal of frustration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does this do exactly the same?

No! They are semantically different.

- the constructor method is called when you create the object in memry.
- the prePersist event is fired right before you persist it into database.

Consider a situation in which you create your object and process some data (which will take a while) and then persist it into database. So thetime may differ.

Comment: In the case you describe, the object would also be persisted together with the data at the same time right? So the registered time would be the same, would it not?

Comment: No! it would not. you call `$object = new MyClass();` and you create the object in memory. some time later, after some processing, you put it into database. So the times may differ